# .htaccess rule, which is correct?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Please check the following two rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can you please answer which one is better to use and why? Apparently seems both is working. Thanks.

Comment: The 2nd one , because the dot in regular expression means anything. The 2nd one escapes it(it means look only for ".html").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok learned a new thing from shashank kadne, that I didn't thought before. So, basically a dot (.) has its own significance in regular expression and it means "anything". to make it instruct as only dot, it should be escaped as "." .

The first rule is wrong. For example, it will allow file.dhtml as a valid rule, which isn't actually.